# Como puedo aplicar un uso de GET con este caracter "/"

Tags: php, mysql

Cómo puedo hacer que mi sitio web de pelicula tenga un enlace así: https://fowmovies.ml/pelicula/bad-boys-for-life . En vez de: https://fowmovies.ml/pelicula?p=bad-boys-for-life

Cómo puedo sustituir el: `?p=bad-boys-for-life` por `/bad-boys-for-life`

Comment: Podrías implementar lo que se conoce como URL amigables, esto se hace generalmente vía `.htaccess`, aquí hay varias preguntas/respuestas que abordan el tema.

Comment: Debes agregar lo que estas haciendo y mostrar un poco más de evidencia que has realizado investigación y el problema que estas enfrentando o error que te genera el proceso que estas realizando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a esto.

**Crear Archivo .htaccess**

Es importante tener en cuanta que PHP no puede leer URLs amigables, por lo tanto tendremos que convertirlas de amigables a no amigables para poder realizar la lectura desde nuestro código, es decir:

```
/blog/10 ⇒ /blog.php?publicacion_id=10
```

Para esto se útiliza el archivo .htaccess, se puede decir que este archivo es el "puente" entre las URLs amigables (que pueden ser leídas por los usuarios de nuestro sitio) y URLs "nativas" (que pueden ser leídas por lenguajes de programación, en este caso PHP).

Entonces, para crear un archivo .htaccess, primero nos debemos meter a la raíz de nuestro proyecto (al mismo nivel donde tenemos nuestro index.php) y ahí crear el archivo con el nombre .htaccess. Una vez creado el archivo en la raíz de nuestro proyecto lo abrimos con nuestro edito de texto favorito.

Una vez abierto empezamos por escribir la siguiente linea:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks: es la linea que nos dice si un directorio es un enlace simbólico, que lo siga.
*RewriteEngine on:* es la linea donde le decimos a Apache que queremos sobre escribir las URLs para crear URLs amigables.
Posteriormente escribimos la ruta de la URL amigable que queremos escucha entre los signos ^ y $:

```
# Sintaxis
RewriteRule ^url-amigable-aqui$ url-no-amigable-va-aqui.php
#En nuestro ejemplo tendríamos la siguiente ruta
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blog.php?publicacion_id=$1
```

- ^blog/([0-9]+)$: es la URL amigable la cual estamos escuchando.
  ([0-9]+) es una expresión regular que nos permite ingresar sólo
  numeros. Puedes leer mas acerca de expresiones regulares aquí.
- blog.php?publicacion_id=$1: es la URL no amigable la cual vamos a
  mostrar una vez que el usuario acceda a la URL amigable. El $1 hace
  referencia al valor de la expresión regular, entonces si la ruta
  fuera blog/10, el $1 tendrá el valor de 10.

Así nos queda el archivo htaccess completo:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blog.php?publicacion_id=$1
```

Con esto ya estamos transformando un URL amigable (la cual un usuario puede leer) a una no amigable (la cual un lenguaje de programación, en este caso PHP, puede leer).

**Leer los Parámetros de la URL en PHP**

Ya que tengamos escritas nuestras URLs (rutas) podemos leer el parametro de publicacion_id dentro de nuestro archivo blog.php. Para esto podemos útilizar la variable super-global $_GET. Nos qudariá así:

```
echo $_GET["publicacion_id"]; // Nos dará el id de la publicación a la cual quieres acceder, en nuestro ejemplo, el ID 10.

//Realizar consulta a la base de datos para obtener la publicación con el ID 10
?>
```

Ahora, con esta variable ya podemos realizar una consulta a la base de datos para obtener la publicación con el ID 10.

A continuación [te dejo el enlace con vídeo](https://youtu.be/oDYkF0RS8u4)

Fuente: https://cursos.mejorcodigo.net/article/urls-amigables-con-php-15

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido. Marca la respuesta como útil si te ha servido, así si alguien tiene la misma duda, puede resolver su interrogante al ingresar al post.